# Puppet: Forcing user to change his password at next login

Tags: rhel, password, puppet

I am using `users' resource to create unix accounts and then set a default password. For this I have written the following manifest .

```
node 'node2.example.com','node3.example.com'{
 user {
 'askar':
  ensure  => 'present',
  managehome => 'true',
  comment => 'man Home',
  home    => '/home/askar',
  shell   => '/bin/bash',
  expiry  => '2016-03-22',
  password => '$1$cs1j/t.D$4Q2Ocr0pulyNTUx/',
  password_min_age => '30',
  password_max_age => '60',
   }
  }
```

It works fine, but I want the user should be forced to change his password at next login. For this I extended the rule with an `exec` resource to run the following command `chage -d 0 askar` so that the user is forced to change the password

```
exec {
'chage':
 command => 'chage -d 0 askar'
 }
}
```

But this is not working for me. Can you please suggest how can I get a user forced to change his password at next login .

Answer (score 0):

It seems `exec` puppet resource looks for the command in the current directory only.

Adding the path of `chage` command resolved the issue for me

```
  $ which chage
  /usr/bin/chage
```

So,the exec resource declaration is as follows

```
 exec {
  'chage':
        path => '/usr/bin/',
        command => 'chage -d 0 askar',
      }
```

Verified that password expired for the user which means the user must change his password at next login.

```
# chage -l askar
Last password change                : Password must be changed 
Password expires                    : Password must be changed
Password inactive                   : password must be changed
Account expires                     : Mar 22, 2016
Minimum number of days between password change          : 30
Maximum number of days between password change          : 60
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```